# using tiny-AES-c for encrypted wireless link

Tags: encryption, aes

I recently cam across an AES implementation in C for embedded systems and have been looking at using it in a wireless point-to-many-points link (or point-to-point for starters).

The code compiles correctly on my platform and it seems to give the correct results when using the test code provided with CTR mode, back to back (this CRT mode is what I require as my packets are of 120 bytes each and cannot be changed).

Essentially the transmitter Tx should use the tiny-AES encryption function to generate a continuous stream of encrypted packets of 120 bytes each, transmit them with a CTR attached and the header etc, and to be received and decrypted on the other end by the receiver Rx.

It is envisaged the transmitter Tx and receiver Rx use exactly the same tiny-AES code with the same key that is known to me only. This key can be set and would be different on different Tx-Rx pairs.

My question relates to the CRT mode in particular and the use of the following functions both on the Tx and the Rx :

```
/* Initialize context calling (iv can be NULL): */
void AES_ctx_init(AES_ctx *ctx, uint32_t keylen, const uint8_t *key, const uint8_t *iv);

/* ... or reset IV or key at some point: */
void AES_ctx_set_key(AES_ctx *ctx, uint32_t keylen, const uint8_t *key);
void AES_ctx_set_iv(AES_ctx *ctx, const uint8_t *iv);
```

So

1. What is the purpose of `AES_ctx_init()` and is this done only once at the start of an encrypt/decrypt session of a secure link ?
2. What is the purpose of the `AES_ctx_set_iv()` function and again, is this done only once at the start of the secured link session ? The comment "... or reset IV or key at some point" is not clear to me – the reason for my question ... That is when does the IV need to be reset when using AES in CRT mode ?
3. Do the Tx and the Rx require to use the very same IV and can this be left as is or does it need to be changed with every new secured link session ? I understand that the secret key would normally be chosen for a Tx/Rx pair and only modified by the user on both when required but normally it would stay the same for every session. Is this generally correct ? Is this the case (or not) for the IV, and at what point does one reset the IV ?

In wireless links, due to noise, and if there is no implementation of a FEC, the receiver will be forced to drop packets due to bad CRCs. In my link the CRC is verified for the received 120 bytes packet (one by one as they are received) and the decryption is initiated to recover the original data if the CRC is correct, but the data is dropped if not. What are the implications of this to the stream of encrypted Tx packets as they keep getting transmitted regardless, as there is no hand-shaking protocol to tell the Tx the Rx dropped a packet due to a CRC error, if any ?

If answers to these questions exist in the form of some further documentation on the tiny-AES I would appreciate some links to it as the notes provided assume people are already familiar with AES etc.

---

So here's some further to the comments/replies already made. Basically the Tx / Rx pair has a pre-defined packet structure with a certain payload, header CRC etc but let’s call this the “packet”. The payload is what I need to encrypt and this is fixed to 120 bytes, not negotiable regardless and it’s in the packet.
So what you are saying is that with each transmission of a packet the Tx and Rx will need to change the nonce with every packet, and both Tx & Rx need to be using the same nonce with each treatment of a packet ?

Say I begin transmission, and have packet(1), packet(2) … packet(n) etc. then with each packet transmitted I need to update the “counter”, and that both transmitter and receiver need to be synchronized so that both use the same nonce in a session ?

This can be problematic when and if, due to noise or interference, the Tx/Rx system loses synchronization as it can happen, and somehow the two independent counters for the nonce are no longer synced and on the same page so-to-speak…
Generally a session would not require more than 2^16 packets on average, so can you see a way around this ? As I said, the option of sending a different nonce with every individual packet is totally out of the question, as the payload is already complete and full.

Another way I thought perhaps you can shed some light if this may work, is through GPS. Say if each Tx and Rx have each a GPS module (which is the case), then timing information could be derived from the GPS clock on both Tx & Rx as both would receive this independently, and some kind of synchronized counter could be rolling to update the nonce on both, say counting from 0 to 2^16 in a session… would you agree ? So even if due to noise/interference, packets are lost by the receiver, the counter would continue updating the nonce with some form of reliable “tick” in the background…

With regards to the source of entropy, well apparently the lampert circuit would provide this for a good PRNG running locally, say for a session of 2^16 packets, but this is not available on my system yet, but could be if we decide to take this further …

What are your thoughts on this as a professional in the field ?
Regards,

Comment: which tiny-AES library are we talking about?

Comment: What is "CRT mode." Do you mean CTR mode? Also, why does this mode help you with a 120 byte packet size? Does this 120 bytes over purely the ciphertext, or does it include the headers and CRC?

Comment: I'm refering to the tiny-AES-c on github. There appears to be only one original version with slight additions that I have not looked into.

Comment: Sorry, yes its the counter mode CTR I'm refering to.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the Tiny AES you're referring to is [tiny-AES-c](https://github.com/kokke/tiny-AES-c) (though your code is a little different than that code; I can't find anywhere that `AES_ctx_set_key` is defined). I assume when you say "CRT mode" you mean CTR mode.

> What is the purpose of AES_ctx_init() and is this done only once at the start of an encrypt/decrypt session of a secure link ?

This initializes the internal data structures. Specifically it performs key expansion which creates the necessary round keys from the master key. In this library, it looks like it would be called once at the beginning of the session, to set the key and IV.

In CTR mode, it is absolutely critical that the Key+Nonce (IV) combination is never reused on two different messages. (CTR mode doesn't technically have an "IV." It has a "nonce," but it looks exactly like an IV and is passed identically in every crypto library I've ever seen.) If you need to reuse a nonce, you must change the key. This generally means that you will have to keep a persistent (i.e. across system resets) running counter on your encrypting device to keep track of the last-used nonce. There are ways to use a semi-random nonce safely, but you need a high-quality source of entropy, which is often not available on embedded devices.

If you pass NULL as the IV/nonce and reuse the key, CTR mode is a nearly worthless encryption scheme.

Since you need to be able to drop packets cleanly, what you'll need to do is send the nonce along with each packet. The nonce is not a secret; it just has to be unique for a given key. The nonce is 16 bytes long. If this is too much data, a common approach is to exchange the first 12 bytes of the nonce at the beginning of the session, and then use the bottom 4 bytes as a counter starting a 0. If sessions can be longer than 2^32 blocks, then you would need to reset the session after you run out of values.

Keep in mind that "blocks" here are 16 bytes long, and each block requires its own nonce. To fit in 120 bytes, you would probably do something like send the 4 byte starting counter, and then append 7 blocks for n, n+1, n+2, ... n+6.

Designing this well is a little complicated, and it's easy to do it wrong and undermine your cryptography. If this is important, you should probably engage someone with experience to design this for you. I do this kind of work, but I'm sure there are many people you could find.

---

> So what you are saying is that with each transmission of a packet the Tx and Rx will need to change the nonce with every packet, and both Tx & Rx need to be using the same nonce with each treatment of a packet ?

Correct. The Tx side will determine the nonce, and the Rx side will consume it. Though they could coordinate somehow other than sending it explicitly, as long as it never repeats, and they always agree. This is one of the benefits of CTR mode; it relies on a "counter" that doesn't necessarily have to be sent.

The clock is nice because it's non-repeating. The tricky part is staying synchronized, while being absolutely certain you don't reuse a nonce. It's easier to stay synchronized if the time window for each nonce is large. It's easier to make sure you never reuse a nonce if the time window is small. Combining a clock-derived nonce with a sequential counter might be a good approach. There will still be ongoing synchronization issues on the receiving side where the receiver needs to try a few different counters (or nonce+counters) to find the right one. But it should be possible.

Note that synchronization assumes that there is a way to distinguish valid plaintext from invalid plaintext. If there is a structure to the plaintext, then you can try one nonce and if the output is gibberish, try another. But if there is no structure to the plaintext, then you have a big problem, because you won't be able to synchronize. By "structure" I mean "can you tell the difference between valid data and random noise.

Using the clock, as long as your window is small enough that you would never reuse a starting nonce, even across resets, you could avoid needing a PRNG. The nonce doesn't have to be random; it just can never repeat.

Note that if you have a 4-byte counter portion, then you have 2^32 blocks, not 2^16.

Comment: Hi Rop, yes that's the one I'm referring to.

Comment: Hi Rob. Just a quick question relating to your statement : "This generally means that you will have to keep a persistent (i.e. across system resets) running counter on your encrypting device to keep track of the last-used nonce.". You mention here the "encrypting device". Does this mean only and only the encrypting device, or the decrypting device equally ? If only the encrypting device requires the random nonce that makes a big difference ... Perhaps this is not the case, but would like to know ...

Comment: Only the the encrypting device. The decrypting device needs to use the nonce that is sent by the encryptor (both sides must use the same nonce).